# Story about people bonded to "Grateful Dead" type bears

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

Read this book quite a while ago in high school, 2004 at the latest. Details are a bit sketchy, any help would be appreciated.

Two people, one male, one female. I think that they meet up in the beginning of the story. The male is "bonded" to a creature who reminds me most strongly of the bears that are commonly associated with the Grateful Dead. He explains at one point to the woman that only men can be bonded to the bears, any women that have tried have...died? gone insane? Can't remember. Part of the bond between them is that he gives the creature some of his blood every so often.

A majority of the story  revolves around them finding and travelling through what sounds like an extraordinarily large warehouse left by a race that came before.

Near the end of the book the woman discovers that women can bond with the GD bears, but their bond is not centered around blood but something else (that I cannot remember).

It was a paperback book. I don't remember there being any other stories in the book, so I don't think analogy. There was either cover art or inside illustration (I don't remember which) which showed something similar to the grateful dead like bears as the "bonded" creatures But the art may have also been little doodles at the header of the chapters, I can't remember.

That's it. Any ideas?

---

Here's an example of the "Grateful Dead bears".
[image: Five bears, dark blue, green, yellow, pink]

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by *"the bears that are commonly associated with the Grateful Dead"*. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Probably small teddy-bearish creatures, c.f. the Hoka or Ewoks.

Comment: You might look at the titles in http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UrsineAliens to see if any of the titles match your memory.

Comment: The bears: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grateful_Dead#mediaviewer/File:GDDancingBears.jpg

Comment: Yes, creatures similar to the wikipedia article posted above. There was either cover art or inside illustration (I don't remember which) which showed something similar to them as the "bonded" creatures.

Comment: Can you give a time frame reference to when you read it?

Comment: I recollect in the trillium series someone giving blood to a creature every so often so they become friends.  I think it may of been golden trillium which Andre Norton wrote (This is not the book of course) and she tends to use creatures in her books so it may be a past work of hers and she has reused a theme.

Comment: I read it in high school, so at least 10 years ago. however, I don't think that the book was new, so it could have been published any time prior to 2004.

Comment: @DajanRa I've put up a bounty for this question. If you remember any additional details, please [edit] them in.

Comment: For some reason this makes me think of Alan Dean Foster, though I can't find a title in the bibliography I Googled up that ties to this for me.

Comment: @SQB: did you read a novel or short fiction? by "cover", do you mean the cover to a novel? a magazine cover? the cover to a collection?

Comment: @RiaByss I did not read anything, I'm not the OP. I'm merely offering a bounty.

Comment: It was a paperback book. I don't remember there being any other stories in the book, so I don't think analogy. By "cover" I mean the picture on the cover of the book. But the art may have also been little doodles at the header of the chapters, I can't remember.

Comment: @DajanRa would you mind [edit]ing that in?