# Dystopian travel through massive warehouse

Tags: story-identification

This book was set in a dystopian future, a man, who has an animal like bond-companion who looks similar to the Grateful Dead bears, meets a woman in or near a large underground warehouse. They travel through the warehouse for several days (maybe longer). The bond companion needs to get blood from the man every so often. The man tells the woman that women are not able to bond and that those who have tried have either died or gone insane. At some point the woman discovers that the creatures can bond with women, but that it is not a blood bond like it is with men.

This may not have been a terribly long book. I read it at least 15 years ago in High School. I remember it as a paper back book with some, but not many, illustrations here and there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80859/story-about-people-bonded-to-grateful-dead-type-bears) unanswered question.

Comment: Was that you asking about this book [before](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80859/story-about-people-bonded-to-grateful-dead-type-bears?lq=1)? Is "Dajan Ra" your secret identity? If you can't get an answer here, another good site for this sort of question is the [BookSleuth Forum](http://forums.abebooks.com/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/abesleuthcom?redirCnt=1&cm_sp=Ftr-_-Home-_-E3) at [AbeBooks.com](http://www.abebooks.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. As to secret identities, you aren't supposed to tell about those are you? So, I can neither confirm or deny.

Comment: If you are the same person, you should just get the accounts merged.